# Z3 unable to find satisfying assignment for simple formula with quantifiers and patterns

Tags: z3, smt, formal-verification

I am currently writing an automatic Verifier for my programming language on top of Z3 as a fun project and I am trying to use it to prove that a fibonacci implementation using a loop is equivalent to one with recursion.

It seems to work if the input program is correct, i.e. it generates reasonable input for Z3 and Z3 says it is unsatisfiable, which means in my context, that the program is correct. But when I changed one variable initialization and thereby render the program incorrect, my verifier came up with the following Z3 formula which doesn't seem too complicated to me, but Z3 says "unknown".

```
(set-option :smt.auto-config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)
(declare-fun fib (Int) Int)
(declare-fun fakeFib (Int) Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)
(assert (forall ((n Int))
   (! (= (fib n)
         (ite (= n 0) 0
            (ite (= n 1) 1
               (+ (fakeFib (- n 1)) (fakeFib (- n 2))))))
      :pattern ((fib n)))))
(assert (forall ((n Int))
   (! (= (fib n) (fakeFib n)) :pattern ((fib n)))))
(assert (>= n 0))
(assert (not (and (<= 0 n) (= 1 (fib 1)) (= 1 (fib 0)))))
(check-sat)
```

Note that the two quantifiers represent the recursive definition of fibonacci. A friend of mine told me this trick to avoid a matching loop: Instead of defining fib as a recursive function, I introduce another function fakeFib for which I don't provide the definition and I use that one in the recursive definition of fib. Also, I tell the verifier that they are equal, but that quantifier only gets a pattern for fib, not for fakeFib. Because of the restrictive patterns, it is incomplete, i.e., it can only prove the correctness of the program as long as looking at one level of recursion suffices to prove it (but it can easily be extended to k levels). But I can live with that restriction in order to avoid matching loops.

The "bug" of the code was that I initialized a variable incorrectly and this eventually lead to the incorrect component `(= 1 (fib 0))` in the last assertion. For the correct program, it would be `(= 0 (fib 0))`.

Some observations:

- If I replace `(= 1 (fib 0))` by `(= 0 (fib 0))`, then Z3 immediately finds that it is unsatisfiable.
- Previously, I did not have the options `(set-option :smt.auto-config false)` and `(set-option :smt.mbqi false)` set and then it ran out of memory on my machine and out of time on rise4fun.
- Setting `(set-option :smt.macro-finder true)` which seems to have worked for people with similar questions didn't work for me. I am guessing that this is caused by the fact that I have two quantifiers for `fib` and not just one.
- I tried using cvc4 as a comparison and it said "unknown" immediately. So my problems don't seem to be Z3 specific.
- The formula is clearly satisfiable. `(= 1 (fib 0))` is `false`, therefore the whole last assertion is automatically true. `(>= n 0)` is also easy to satisfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Z3 expert but maybe I can shed a bit of light.

By disabling MBQI you are disabling the ability of Z3 to produce models for quantified formulas, so I guess that when Z3 cannot find a way to prove your problem unsatisfiable, it quickly reports it as `unknown`.

Note that a model for your problem needs to be satisfied by the four assertions, not only by the last two. As you point out Z3 cannot eliminate your first assert as if it were a macro, because you provide two definitions for `fib n`.

If you enable MBQI you will see that Z3 tries to find a model, and consumes quite a lot of memory on it! I presume that this is because the only way to satisfy your specification requires building the recursive function `fib`, feature that Z3 does not support.

**how I will approach this**

What you are doing right now it is a nice trick that allows Z3 to expand `fib` definition as much as needed in order to prove a problem `unsat`. But it does not play nice with the model finder, because you indirectly introduce a recursive definition.

So, if Z3 reports `unsat` then you know that your program is correct. If it reports `unknown`, you have to start an iterative process. Before this, you remove the second assert `(= (fib n) (fakeFib n))` to prevent an infinite loop constructing the model.

1. In each iteration you provide the k-unfolding of `fib`, where `fib(k+1)` is abstracted in terms of `fakeFib`. You can leave `fakeFib n` unconstrained, or you may impose light constraints on it (e.g. must be a positive integer), without adding recursion.
2. If Z3 reports `unsat`, then your program is correct.
3. If Z3 reports `sat`, you must check whether the returned model is consistent with `fib`. If it is consistent, then you got a counterexample. If it is not consistent, then you increase `k` and goto step 1.

You may want to read about k-induction, what I propose you is more or less that.

Comment: Hm. Ok. I guess that makes sense. I am guessing with MBQI it probably extended the fib function forever and went out of memory/time that way. That means I cannot use models at all and just have to rely on "unsat => correct program" and "sat => incorrect program and I know what went wrong" and "unknown => probably incorrect program, but no idea what went wrong"

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for this explanation. I think, in my first version, I will just reject everything that ends up "unknown" and tell the user "wasn't able to prove x", and in later versions, I will add k induction. :) The keyword alone was already very useful for me since I found several interesting papers about it.